# How can I control thread(control ball speed)?

Tags: java

I have a question.
I'm studying java.
In this code, I want to slower/faster the ball that created after I clicked "slower/faster" Menu button.
I mean, when I added ball and when the ball I added is moving, and then I click slow or fast button, and the ball that was moving has the same speed, and the ball that created after I clicked button, that ball's speed have to be changed.

I tried lock and unlock method in BallRunnable class, but it doesn't work.
Could you give me an advice? Thanks :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class BallBounce {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new BounceFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
/**
    A runnable that animates a bouncing ball.
*/
class BallRunnable implements Runnable {
    public BallRunnable(Ball aBall, JPanel ballPanel) { 
        ball = aBall; this.ballPanel = ballPanel;
        ballLock = new ReentrantLock();
    }
    public void run() {
        ballLock.lock();
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= STEPS; i++) {
                ball.move(ballPanel.getBounds()); // update the location of the ball
                ballPanel.paint(ballPanel.getGraphics());
                Thread.sleep((long)(DELAY * change));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("what"); }
        finally { ballLock.unlock(); }
    }
    public static void print() { System.out.println(DELAY * change); }
    public static void setdoublechange() {
        change = change * 2;
    }
    public static void sethalfchange() {
        change = change / 2;
    }
    private Ball ball;
    private JPanel ballPanel;
    public static final int STEPS = 1000;
    public static final int DELAY = 3;
    private static double change = 1;
    private static Lock ballLock;
}
class BallRunnable2 implements Runnable {
    public BallRunnable2(Ball aBall, JPanel ballPanel) { 
        ball = aBall; this.ballPanel = ballPanel;
    }
    public void run() {
        ballLock.lock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            for (int i = 1; i <= STEPS; i++) {
                ball.move(ballPanel.getBounds()); // update the location of the ball
                ballPanel.paint(ballPanel.getGraphics());
                Thread.sleep(DELAY * change);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        finally { ballLock.unlock(); }
    }
    public static void setdoublechange() {
        change = change * 2;
    }
    public static void sethalfchange() {
        change = change / 2;
    }
    private Ball ball;
    private JPanel ballPanel;
    public static final int STEPS = 1000;
    public static final int DELAY = 3;
    public static int change = 1;
    private Lock ballLock;
}
/**
    A ball that moves and bounces off the edges of a rectangle
*/
class Ball {
    /**
        Moves the ball to the next position, reversing direction if it hits one of the edges
     */
    public void move(Rectangle2D bounds) { // java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
        x += dx; y += dy;
        if (x < bounds.getMinX()) { x = bounds.getMinX(); dx = -dx; }
        if (x + XSIZE >= bounds.getMaxX()) { x = bounds.getMaxX() - XSIZE; dx= -dx; }
        if (y < bounds.getMinY()) { y = bounds.getMinY(); dy = -dy; }
        if (y + YSIZE >= bounds.getMaxY()) { y = bounds.getMaxY() - YSIZE; dy = -dy; }
    }
    /**
        Gets the shape of the ball at its current position.
     */
    public Ellipse2D getShape() { return new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, XSIZE, YSIZE); }

    private static final int XSIZE = 15;
    private static final int YSIZE = 15;
    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;
    private double dx = 1;
    private double dy = 1;
}
/**
    The panel that draws the balls.
*/
class BallPanel extends JPanel {
    /**
        Add a ball to the panel.
        @param b the ball to add
     */
    public void add(Ball b) {
        balls.add(b);
    }
    
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (Ball b : balls) { g2.fill(b.getShape()); }
    }
    private List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();
}
class BounceFrame extends JFrame {
    public BounceFrame() {
        setTitle("BounceThread");
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        ballPanel = new BallPanel(); add(ballPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        addButton(buttonPanel, "Add 1", new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { addBall1(); }
        });
        addButton(buttonPanel, "Add 2", new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { addBall2(); }
        });
        addButton(buttonPanel, "Close", new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { System.exit(0); }
        });
        // addButton(buttonPanel, "Close", (ActionEvent event) -> System.exit(0));
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        JMenu speedMenu = new JMenu("Speed");
        JMenuItem fasterItem = speedMenu.add(new fasterAction("Faster"));
        JMenuItem slowerItem = speedMenu.add(new slowerAction("Slower"));
        
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(speedMenu);
    }
    private void addButton(Container container, String title, ActionListener listener) {
        JButton button = new JButton(title);
        container.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
    }
    /**
        Adds a bouncing ball to the canvas and starts a thread to make it bounce
     */
    public void addBall1() {
        Ball b = new Ball();
        ballPanel.add(b);
        Runnable r = new BallRunnable(b, ballPanel);
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }
    public void addBall2() {
        Ball b1 = new Ball();
        Ball b2 = new Ball();
        ballPanel.add(b1);
        ballPanel.add(b2);      
        Runnable r1 = new BallRunnable(b1, ballPanel);
        Runnable r2 = new BallRunnable2(b2, ballPanel);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
    
    private BallPanel ballPanel;
    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 450;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 350; 
}

class fasterAction extends AbstractAction {
    public fasterAction(String name) { super(name); }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        BallRunnable.sethalfchange();
        BallRunnable2.sethalfchange();
    }
}
class slowerAction extends AbstractAction {
    public slowerAction(String name) { super(name); }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        BallRunnable.setdoublechange();
        BallRunnable2.setdoublechange();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whose code is this? Where did you find it?

Comment: It's my school assignment.

Comment: btw: you __must not__ change a component off the EDT (or did that change in recent years, didn't touch swing for quite a while @HovercraftFullOfEels)

Comment: @kleopatra: Swing hasn't changed. It's pretty much petrified in its current state. A sad, dying library found mainly in corners of academia.

Answer (score 0):

Increase `Thread.sleep()` value (it is in milliseconds)

Comment: Well... I think it's not an corrent way...

Comment: Since your `dx` and `dy` are in range [-1:1] only left thing to reduce is number of times ball is moved/painted per second. And you do that by making it sleep for longer periods of time. If yours `dx` and `dy` values were bigger you would be able to reduce those to make ball make lesser steps but since you cant move less number of pixels, make it move less often

Answer (score 0):

Changing `dx` and/or `dy` of the ball (when a certain condition is met).

If I am correct <`dx`, `dy`> is the velocity of the ball.